# Cambiar color de fondo de datables

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Tengo unos datatables a los que quiero cambiarles el color de fondo en una pagina en especifico, por lo agregue un style para poder cambiarlo:

```
table.display tbody:hover td{
background-color: red !important;
}
```

Lo hago de esta forma pero solo me cambia el color cuando el cursor esta posicionado en las tablas. Lo estoy haciendo por css debido a que por jquery no me funciono. Lo intente de esta forma:

```
for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) { 
     $('td', newrow).eq(i).css("background-color", "#6600cc !important");
}
```

Pero nada, no hay cambios de color en las tablas.

Comment: Quitale el `:hover`

Comment: Nada, si se lo quito no me aplica el cambio de color

Answer (score 1):

Lo puedes hacer a través de estilos, como se muestra a continuación

```css
table { 
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: lemonchiffon;
  border-collapse: collapse; 
}
table th { 
  background-color: goldenrod;
  color: white; 
}
table td, 
table th{ 
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid goldenrod; 
 }
```

```html
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>Item 1</td>
  <td>Item 2</td>
  <td>Item 3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Item 1</td>
  <td>Item 2</td>
  <td>Item 3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Item 1</td>
  <td>Item 2</td>
  <td>Item 3</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

puedes utilizar esta cascada, solamente tienes que asegurarte que la tabla tenga el nombre de la clase "display" tal como lo especificas:
Digamos que sea este caso el de tu tabla:

```
<table class="table display table-bordered table-hover dt-responsive">
... y demás código html de la tabla.
```

La cascada puede quedar así:

```
<style>
  .table.display  tbody tr:nth-child(odd) td,
  .table.display tbody tr:nth-child(odd) th {
   background-color: #F2DEE0;
   }

  .table.display tbody tr:nth-child(even) td,
  .table.display tbody tr:nth-child(even) th {
  background-color: #8D3841;
  color:#fff;
  }
</style>
```